# Qt macdeployqt deploy not working properly

Tags: qt, macdeployqt

I've got an application using `sqlite` that works fine when running it through the compiler. (Both debug and release more). However when I try to deploy it with `macdeployqt` I get the following error:

```
ERROR: no file at "/opt/local/lib/mysql55/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib"
```

When trying my app on a mac that does not have `Qt` installed it crashes randomly after a few minutes.

Any ideas? I am not using `mysql` in my app just `sqlite`.

Comment: Do you get that error when running macdeployqt, or afterwards when running the application? For the crash/exit, check if the “Console" application shows anything useful in terms of output, otherwise run it in a debugger.

Comment: I get that error when running macdeployqt

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to [build sql plugin](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html) at first.